# Django duplicate tables with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, database

I have multiple databases one is sqlite and the others in postgresql using one app, when i migrate bases 'using routers' all the tables in models.py gets created in all the bases including sqlite or nothing if i added return false to the allow_migrate function.

how to stop duplicate tables from happening ??

this is my code 'example'

`settings.py`

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.router.sqlite_Router','routers.router.postgres_router_1','routers.router.postgres_router_2']

DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'auth_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'postgres_db_1': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=test'
        },
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST':'localhost',
    },
    'postgres_db_2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=test'
        },
        'NAME': 'test2',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST':'localhost',
    }
}
```

`router.py`

```
class sqlite_Router:
    route_app_labels = {'auth', 'contenttypes','admin','sessions'}
    database = 'auth_db'
    ....
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        model = hints.get('model')
        if model:
            usedb = getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)
            if app_label in self.route_app_labels and usedb == self.database:
                return db == self.database # True
            #else: return False # <== i only get django_migrations, no other tables
        return None

class postgres_router_1:
    route_app_labels = {'test'}
    database = 'postgres_db_1'
    ....
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        model = hints.get('model')
        if model:
            usedb = getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)
            if app_label in self.route_app_labels and usedb == self.database:
                return db == self.database # True
            #else: return False # <== i only get django_migrations, no other tables
        return None

class postgres_router_2:
    route_app_labels = {'test'}
    database = 'postgres_db_2'
    ....
    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        model = hints.get('model')
        if model:
            usedb = getattr(model._meta, 'database', None)
            if app_label in self.route_app_labels and usedb == self.database:
                return db == self.database # True
            #else: return False # <== i only get django_migrations, no other tables
        return None
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES = models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES + ('database', )
class postgres_one_test(models.Model):
    postgres_test_one = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.postgres_test_one
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'test'
        database = 'postgres_db_1'
.... 


class postgres_two_test(models.Model):
    postgres_test_two = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.postgres_test_two
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'test'
        database = 'postgres_db_2'


...
```

Comment: Probably not relevant to the problem but doesn't it have to be called `PORT` instead of `POSRT`?

Comment: @Marco edited , yes it's not relevant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found **A** solution.

changed **django.db.models.options**

added '**database**' in the **DEFAULT_NAMES**

and '**self.database = None**' in the '****init****' of '**class Options**',

and the sqlite_router 'django apps->**allow_migrate**' to the default

```
if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
    return db == self.database
return None
```

and removed the '**return False**' from the **allow_migrate**.

also removed

```
models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES = models.options.DEFAULT_NAMES + ('database', )
```

from models as it's not needed.

everything else is the same